# Bootstrap - Form - radius values with visibility changes

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using bootstrap for my site. I have a price table which I need to adapt depending on the width of the device. I'm using `<div class="hidden-xs">` and `<div class="visible-xs">` for that.

for PCs/Tables the layout of my price table is based in columns and you have to select the price with a radius input. Example:

```
 <form>
    <div id="pricesForPC" class="hidden-xs">

Price 1------Price 2----Price 3

--Columns with description---

radius-------radius-----radius

id="price"--id="price"--id="price"

value=1------value=2----value=3

    </div> 

And for cellphones I will show it on rows:

    <div id="pricesForMobile" class="visible-xs">

Price 1 -radius button--id="price" --value=1

Price 2 -radius button--id="price" --value=2

Price 3 -radius button--id="price" --value=3

    </div> 

--Submit button--

    </form>
```

This is working ok as it shows and hides the prices in columns or rows as you resize the browser.

The issue I have is the selected price.

If you have selected a price in the **"pricesForPC"** and the resize the browser for a xs size the **"pricesForMobile"** table won't show the previously selected price.

So if I press submit it will submit the value selected on the "pricesforPC" table although the "pricesForMobile" table has no price selected.

Is not possible to check the price value is empty as

```
 $('input[name="price"]:checked').val();
```

gives the selected value on **"pricesforPC"** no matter if its hidden or not.

I want to avoid to load with php the form corresponding to the browser width as I will lose page adaptability. I cannot change the radius button also.

Thanks for your help.

B/R.

Answer (score 0):

What I finnally did was to create a hidden field id=price. Then I set the prices options Ids for pc as "pricePc" and for mobile as "priceMobile". When any of them changes I set the new value to the hidden field "price" and I change the other radio option.

For example, if i'm in a PC I will see only radio buttons of pricePc. If I check pricePC=2 ==> price=2 and priceMobile=2.

This way the values are the same no matter the width.

B/R.